# monetisation labels won`t work as espected for AM 2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is anyone using Monetization Category Labels in latest WSO2 API Manager 2.0?

I made required changes in the tenant-conf.json and put both *EnableMonetization* and  *IsUnlimitedTierPaid* to true. The labels are there, but all tier compilations are always with "free" label.

I have changed Subscription Tier "Silver" Billing Plan from "free" to  "Commercial" and labels are same "free".

I even created new Subscription Tier and no lack.

The only one option is worked: If I activate unlimited Subscription Tier only when when label will be "paid" and if I will activate  unlimited AND any other Tier when label will be "fremium".

It looks like AM is counting any Subscription Tier as free tier and Billing Plan option is not working.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue in APIM which is fixed in APIM 2.1.0. It will be released soon. Please find the APIM 2.1.0 Alpha from [1]

If you are in a dev environment, you can get the updated package for APIM 2.0.0 through WUM [2]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v2.1.0-alpha

[2] http://wso2.com/update

Comment: Thanks. May you point me to best upgrade manual? I will wait for full 2.1 release any way.